# Getting mongodb error when changing the spring boot version

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, version

Error
exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified

Changed spring boot version to 2.5.4 from 2.1.5

I have tried with by changing the version. How to fix this?